# Why random is behaving differently here?

Tags: java, random

Can anybody please explain why the below code gives output `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

```
 Random random = new Random(-6732303926L);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        System.out.println(random.nextInt(10)+" ");
```

From Java API [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) I can see constructor `Random(long seed)` creates a new random number generator using a single `long seed`. So, this will be random again, why this gves a fixed output every time?

Comment: You found a cool seed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Is it special case? I found this code snippet.

Comment: It's as much a special case as if you had used the seed `1234567890` or `131215151351` or any other seed. The fact that it outputs something that has meaning to us humans, doesn't mean it isn't random (though still based on the seed and the algorithm).

Comment: If you change the seed, it works as expected.  I think you found a magical seed.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Downvoter can you please comment on this?

Comment: this forum is getting more and more hostile. I don't see a reason why someone would downvote this question.

Comment: @arunmoezhi Thanks for the upvote :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From Java API Random I can see constructor Random(long seed) creates a new random number generator using a single long seed. So, this will be random again, why this gves a fixed output every time?

A [seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) is used to generate the same output (from random operations) in different runs of the program. So, each time you create the `Random` object with the same seed, it will output the same result.

**Note:**
The seed you chose has a particular output, that is `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, but it doesn't mean anything. There will also be some other seeds with that same output.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 5):

It gives a fixed output every time because you are using the same seed.  The particular seed you are using happens to give the sequential output: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

Comment: Again. From the constructor as I mentioned it will generate the random number as per javadoc.

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari It will generate a random number based on the seed you give it.  If you use the same seed in multiple instances of `Random` it will always produce the same result.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari You get a sequence of *pseudo-random* numbers which are determined by the seed.

Comment: @fvrghl +1 for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

Every weird sequence has a non-zero probability of occurring :)

[image]
[image]